# WordPress shared user tables aren't working | You do not have sufficient permissions

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am following this tutorial on how to do shared user tables with dashboard.mysite.com and site.mysite.com. Dashboard is the site that has the user tables. I got this error when I logged into site:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

I try to follow the tutorial, but on wp-capabilities.php, there is not this line: `$this->cap_key = $wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities';` Is the tutorial outdated